# Excel 2010 Using VBA to print sheet(s)

Tags: vba, excel, printing, excel-2010

I've been using the following code to print a sheet (with VBA) in a workbook.  We are currently using Excel 2010.  I've used this code for a long time and now I have a user who says the printed copy comes out extremely small and light.

The user says she has to enlarge the print to a #12 and bold all the info on the sheet so that the information is readable. Otherwise she claims it is impossible to read because it is so small.

Is there any properties I can add to this code or make changes to the existing properties to ensure the copy is more readable?

Would it be better to print to a PDF file?

Thanks for your help and suggestions.........

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

     .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
     .PrintTitleColumns = ""
     .PrintArea = ""

     .CenterHeader = "&A "
     .RightFooter = "&""Arial,Regular""&8&P of &N"

     .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.35)
     .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.35)
     .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
     .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
     .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
     .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
     .PrintGridlines = True
     .CenterHorizontally = True
     .Orientation = xlLandscape
     .Zoom = False
     .FitToPagesWide = 1
     .FitToPagesTall = False

End With

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

Comment: Does she have a different printer than everyone else?  I once had an issue where an incorrect driver caused my excel charts to print wrong on another computer.

Comment: @NinjaLlama.............Generally users at an Admin Offices all share the same printer.  One possibility is that she is the only person in that Admin Office using this macro; which is why I haven't heard from anyone else.  It could be the same or a different printer at a different Admin Office; I don't really know since they are spread out all over the country.  I given her some instructions to set the default font and size on her machine and we'll see if that helps any.  Thanks for responding....